# Ajax Dynamic Archives not showing correct results

Tags: posts, jquery, ajax, html

Im baffled on why this is not showing the correct results, when selecting the month alone and say 100 posts are on the site, only 3 show up, then if you select the category and month the proper show up.

here is the archives template

```
<div id="archive-browser">
<div>
<h4>Month</h4>

<select id="month-choice">
<option val="no-choice"> &mdash; </option>
<?php wp_get_archives(array('type'    => 'monthly', 'format'  => 'option')); ?>
</select>
</div>

<div>
<h4>Category</h4>

<?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none= -- ');?> 
</div>
</div>

<div id="archive-wrapper">
<div id="archive-pot"></div>
</div>
```

here is the archives getter

```
<?php

/*
    Template Name: Archives Getter
*/

$year = trim($_POST['digwp_y']);
$month = trim($_POST['digwp_m']);
$cat = trim($_POST['digwp_c']);
$querystring = "year=$year&monthnum=$month&cat=$cat&posts_per_page=-1";
query_posts($querystring); 

?>

<?php if (($year == '') && ($month == '') && ($cat == '-1')) { ?>

<table id="archives-table"><tr><td style='text-align: center; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px;'>Please choose from above.</td></tr></table>

<?php } else { ?>

<table id="archives-table">
    <?php    
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'PostThumb', true); ?>" alt="" style="width: 35px;" /></td>
                <td><a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                <td><?php comments_popup_link(' ', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?></td>
                <td><?php the_date('m/j/Y'); ?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php 
        endwhile; else:

            echo "<tr><td style='text-align: center; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px;'>Nothing found.</td></tr>";

        endif; 
    ?>
</table>
```

and finally the jquery code

```
jQuery(function($) {
$("#archive-wrapper").height($("#archive-pot").height());
$("#archive-browser select").change(function() {
$("#archive-pot")
    .empty()
    .html("<div style='text-align: center; padding: 30px;'>loading...</div>");

var dateArray = $("#month-choice").val().split("/");
var y = dateArray[3];
var m = dateArray[4];
var c = $("#cat").val();

$.ajax({
    url: "/archive-getter/",
    dataType: "html",
    type: "POST",
    data: ({
        "digwp_y": y,
        "digwp_m" : m,
        "digwp_c" : c
    }),
    success: function(data) {
        $("#archive-pot").html(data);
        $("#archive-wrapper").animate({
            height: $("#archives-table tr").length * 50
        });
    }
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what i ended up with which works nicely.

functions.php part

```
<?php

function scripts_enqueue() {
if(is_page('archives')) {
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax_dropdown', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/loadposts.js',array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax_dropdown', 'myajax', array('custom_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('nonce-ajax-dropdown'), 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts_enqueue' );

function wp_ajax_load_posts(){

if(!wp_verify_nonce( $_GET['_wpnonce'], 'nonce-ajax-dropdown'))
    die( 'Go away!' );

$args = array(
    'year' => trim($_GET['year']),
    'monthnum' => trim($_GET['month']),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'cat' => trim($_GET['cat'] != "-1") ? trim($_GET['cat']) : 0,
);

$ajaxsort = new WP_Query($args);
?>
<table id="archives-table">
    <?php if ($ajaxsort->have_posts()) : while ($ajaxsort->have_posts()) : $ajaxsort->the_post();?>
            <tr>
                <td><a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                <td><?php the_time('m/j/Y'); ?></td>
        <td><?php comments_popup_link('0 Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?></td>
        <td><?php the_category();?>
            </tr>
    <?php 
        endwhile; else:
            echo "<tr><td style='text-align: center; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px;'>Nothing found.</td></tr>";
        endif; 
    ?>
</table>
<?php
    exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts', 'wp_ajax_load_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts', 'wp_ajax_load_posts');
```

jquery part

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#archive-browser select").change(function() {
    $(".message").hide();
    $("#archive-content").empty().html("<div style='text-align: center; padding: 30px;'><img src='http://i.imgur.com/TA3o5.gif' /></div>");
    var date = $('#month-choice option:selected').val();
    var dateArray = $("#month-choice").val().split("/");
    var year = dateArray[3];
    var month = dateArray[4];
    var cat = $('#cat').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: myajax.ajaxurl,
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            action: 'load_posts',
            _wpnonce: myajax.custom_nonce,
            cat: cat,
            month: month,
            year: year,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (date == 'no-choice' && cat == "-1") {
                $("#archive-content").empty().html('<table class="message" id="archives-table"><tr><td style="text-align: center; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px;">Please choose from above.</td></tr></table>');
            } else {
                $("#archive-content").empty().html(data);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be difficult to debug something like this since I don't have your data on my server but you are doing several things that strike me as dicey.

**First**, you are using `query_posts`. Do not use `query_posts`.

> It should be noted that using this to **replace the main query** on a page
>   can **increase page loading times**, in worst case scenarios **more than
>   doubling the amount of work needed or more**. While easy to use, the
>   function is also **prone to confusion and problems** later on. See the
>   note further below on caveats for details.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts (emphasis mine)

**Second**, you are running your query before you check to see if you *want to run a query*. That is, before this line:

```
<?php if (($year == '') && ($month == '') && ($cat == '-1')) { ?>
```

Why would you run a query and then check to see whether you want to tell user they haven't filled in all the requirements they for the query to run?

**Third**, this...

```
if (($year == '') && ($month == '') && ($cat == '-1')) {
```

... is a strange condition. If is `false` if `$cat` is empty. Presumably, your form sets that value to `-1` but that brings me to...

**Fourth**, you appear to be trusting user supplied data 100%. `POST` is no more (maybe 1% more) secure than `GET`. Unless there is validation somewhere not posted, a malicious user could potentially push unsafe data through that query.

**Fifth**, you are not using the [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) and this is exactly the kind of thing it is meant for.